# Functions return successfully but BMX160 sensor does produce any data

Tags: c, embedded, stm32

I am implementing the bmi160 and bmm150 drivers from Bosch in order to get data from the BMX160 (pinout board made by DFRobot) because from what I have gathered. I changed the chip id to match the bmx160 chip id. Upon all the initializations I am given valid returns of 0 yet when I get to reading the data, I do not get good data from the chip. I have made sure the device is getting voltage and is found by my board (STM32F0). I2C clock is set to the standard mode with a default clock speed.

```
/* USER CODE BEGIN Header */
/**
 ******************************************************************************
 * @file           : main.c
 * @brief          : Main program body
 ******************************************************************************
 * @attention
 *
 * Copyright (c) 2022 STMicroelectronics.
 * All rights reserved.
 *
 * This software is licensed under terms that can be found in the LICENSE file
 * in the root directory of this software component.
 * If no LICENSE file comes with this software, it is provided AS-IS.
 *
 ******************************************************************************
 */
/* USER CODE END Header */
/* Includes ------------------------------------------------------------------*/
#include "main.h"
#include "bmm150.h"
#include "bmi160.h"
#include <stdio.h>
// #include "stm32f0xx_hal_uart.h"
/* Private includes ----------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN Includes */

/* USER CODE END Includes */

/* Private typedef -----------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN PTD */

/* USER CODE END PTD */

/* Private define ------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN PD */
/* USER CODE END PD */

/* Private macro -------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN PM */

/* USER CODE END PM */

/* Private variables ---------------------------------------------------------*/
I2C_HandleTypeDef hi2c1;
// UART_HandleTypeDef huart1;

struct bmi160_dev bmi;
struct bmm150_dev bmm;
struct bmm150_settings bmm_settings;
struct bmm150_mag_data mag;
struct bmi160_sensor_data accel;
struct bmi160_sensor_data gyro;
int8_t rslt, rslt1, rslt2, rslt3, rslt4, rslt5, rslt6, rslt7;
int8_t rslt_data, rslt_data1, rslt_data2;
/* USER CODE BEGIN PV */

/* USER CODE END PV */

/* Private function prototypes -----------------------------------------------*/
void SystemClock_Config(void);
static void MX_GPIO_Init(void);
static void MX_I2C1_Init(void);
// static void MX_USART1_UART_Init(void);
/* USER CODE BEGIN PFP */
/* Auxiliary function declarations */
int8_t bmm150_aux_read(uint8_t reg_addr, uint8_t *aux_data, uint16_t len, void *intf_ptr);
int8_t bmm150_aux_write(uint8_t reg_addr, uint8_t *aux_data, uint16_t len, void *intf_ptr);
/* USER CODE END PFP */

/* Private user code ---------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN 0 */
uint8_t Buffer[25] = {0};
uint8_t Space[] = " - ";
uint8_t StartMSG[] = "Starting I2C Scanning: \r\n";
uint8_t EndMSG[] = "Done! \r\n\r\n";

int8_t user_i2c_read(uint8_t id, uint8_t reg_addr, uint8_t *data, uint16_t len)
{
  int8_t rslt = 0; /* Return 0 for Success, non-zero for failure */

  HAL_StatusTypeDef status = HAL_OK;

  while (HAL_I2C_IsDeviceReady(&hi2c1, (uint8_t)(id << 1), 3, 100) != HAL_OK)
  {
    rslt = 0;
  }

  status = HAL_I2C_Master_Transmit(&hi2c1, (uint8_t)(id << 1), &reg_addr, 1, 1000);
  if (status != HAL_OK)
  {
    rslt = (-1);
  }
  HAL_Delay(100);
  status = HAL_I2C_Master_Receive(&hi2c1, (uint8_t)(id << 1), data, len, 10000);
  if (status != HAL_OK)
  {
    rslt = (-1);
  }

  return rslt;
}

int8_t user_i2c_write(uint8_t id, uint8_t reg_addr, uint8_t *data, uint16_t len)
{

  int8_t rslt = 0; /* Return 0 for Success, non-zero for failure */

  HAL_StatusTypeDef status = HAL_OK;

  while (HAL_I2C_IsDeviceReady(&hi2c1, (uint8_t)(id << 1), 3, 100) != HAL_OK)
  {
  }

  uint8_t tx_buffer[len + 1];
  tx_buffer[0] = reg_addr;
  memcpy(&tx_buffer[1], data, len);

  status = HAL_I2C_Master_Transmit(&hi2c1, (uint8_t)(id << 1), tx_buffer, len + 1, 1000);
  if (status != HAL_OK)
  {
    rslt = (-1);
  }

  return rslt;
}

void user_delay_ms(uint32_t period)
{
  HAL_Delay(period);
}

/* USER CODE END 0 */

/**
 * @brief  The application entry point.
 * @retval int
 */
int main(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 1 */
  uint8_t i = 0, ret;
  /* USER CODE END 1 */

  /* MCU Configuration--------------------------------------------------------*/

  /* Reset of all peripherals, Initializes the Flash interface and the Systick. */
  HAL_Init();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN Init */

  /* USER CODE END Init */

  /* Configure the system clock */
  SystemClock_Config();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN SysInit */

  /* USER CODE END SysInit */

  /* Initialize all configured peripherals */
  MX_GPIO_Init();
  MX_I2C1_Init();

  // rslt = i2c_ping_device(&hi2c1, 0x00);
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 2 */
  bmi.id = BMI160_I2C_ADDR;
  bmi.chip_id = BMI160_CHIP_ID;
  bmi.intf = BMI160_I2C_INTF;
  bmi.read = &user_i2c_read;
  bmi.write = &user_i2c_write;
  bmi.delay_ms = &user_delay_ms;

  bmm.chip_id = BMM150_DEFAULT_I2C_ADDRESS;
  bmm.intf = BMM150_I2C_INTF;
  bmm.read = (bmm150_read_fptr_t)bmm150_aux_read;
  bmm.write = (bmm150_write_fptr_t)bmm150_aux_write;
  bmm.delay_us = &user_delay_ms;
  bmm.intf_ptr = bmm.chip_id;

  rslt = bmi160_init(&bmi);
  // pingStatus = i2cs_ping_device(BMI160_I2C_ADDR);

  bmi.aux_cfg.aux_sensor_enable = BMI160_ENABLE;
  bmi.aux_cfg.aux_i2c_addr = bmm.chip_id;
  bmi.aux_cfg.manual_enable = BMI160_ENABLE;
  bmi.aux_cfg.aux_rd_burst_len = BMI160_AUX_READ_LEN_3;

  rslt1 = bmi160_aux_init(&bmi);
  rslt2 = bmm150_init(&bmm);

  bmi.accel_cfg.odr = BMI160_ACCEL_ODR_100HZ;
  bmi.accel_cfg.range = BMI160_ACCEL_RANGE_2G;
  bmi.accel_cfg.bw = BMI160_ACCEL_BW_NORMAL_AVG4;
  bmi.accel_cfg.power = BMI160_ACCEL_NORMAL_MODE;

  bmi.gyro_cfg.odr = BMI160_GYRO_ODR_100HZ;
  bmi.gyro_cfg.range = BMI160_GYRO_RANGE_2000_DPS;
  bmi.gyro_cfg.bw = BMI160_GYRO_BW_NORMAL_MODE;
  bmi.gyro_cfg.power = BMI160_GYRO_NORMAL_MODE;

  rslt3 = bmi160_set_sens_conf(&bmi);

  bmm_settings.preset_mode = BMM150_PRESETMODE_REGULAR;
  rslt4 = bmm150_set_presetmode(&bmm_settings, &bmm);

  bmm_settings.pwr_mode = BMM150_POWERMODE_FORCED;
  rslt5 = bmm150_set_op_mode(&bmm_settings, &bmm);

  uint8_t aux_addr = 0x42;
  uint8_t mag_data[8] = {0};

  uint8_t index;

  bmi.aux_cfg.aux_odr = 8;
  rslt6 = bmi160_config_aux_mode(&bmi);

  rslt7 = bmi160_set_aux_auto_mode(BMM150_REG_CHIP_ID, &bmi);

  /* USER CODE END 2 */

  /* Infinite loop */
  /* USER CODE BEGIN WHILE */
  while (1)
  {
    user_delay_ms(100);
    rslt_data = bmi160_get_sensor_data((BMI160_ACCEL_SEL | BMI160_GYRO_SEL), &accel, &gyro, &bmi);
    rslt_data1 = bmi160_read_aux_data_auto_mode(mag_data, &bmi);
    rslt_data2 = bmm150_aux_mag_data(mag_data, &mag, &bmm);
    /* USER CODE END WHILE */
    printf("****************\n");
    printf("ACC X: %d, Y: %d, Z: %d\n", accel.x, accel.y, accel.z);
    printf("GYRO X: %d, Y: %d, Z: %d\n", gyro.x, gyro.y, gyro.z);
    printf("MAG X : %d Y : %d Z : %d\n", mag.x, mag.y, mag.z);
    printf("################\n");
    /* USER CODE BEGIN 3 */
  }
  /* USER CODE END 3 */
}

/**
 * @brief System Clock Configuration
 * @retval None
 */
void SystemClock_Config(void)
{
  RCC_OscInitTypeDef RCC_OscInitStruct = {0};
  RCC_ClkInitTypeDef RCC_ClkInitStruct = {0};
  RCC_PeriphCLKInitTypeDef PeriphClkInit = {0};

  /** Initializes the RCC Oscillators according to the specified parameters
   * in the RCC_OscInitTypeDef structure.
   */
  RCC_OscInitStruct.OscillatorType = RCC_OSCILLATORTYPE_HSI;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.HSIState = RCC_HSI_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.HSICalibrationValue = RCC_HSICALIBRATION_DEFAULT;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLState = RCC_PLL_NONE;
  if (HAL_RCC_OscConfig(&RCC_OscInitStruct) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /** Initializes the CPU, AHB and APB buses clocks
   */
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.ClockType = RCC_CLOCKTYPE_HCLK | RCC_CLOCKTYPE_SYSCLK | RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK1;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.SYSCLKSource = RCC_SYSCLKSOURCE_HSI;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.AHBCLKDivider = RCC_SYSCLK_DIV1;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB1CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV1;

  if (HAL_RCC_ClockConfig(&RCC_ClkInitStruct, FLASH_LATENCY_0) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  PeriphClkInit.PeriphClockSelection = RCC_PERIPHCLK_I2C1;
  PeriphClkInit.I2c1ClockSelection = RCC_I2C1CLKSOURCE_SYSCLK;
  if (HAL_RCCEx_PeriphCLKConfig(&PeriphClkInit) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
}

/**
 * @brief I2C1 Initialization Function
 * @param None
 * @retval None
 */
static void MX_I2C1_Init(void)
{

  /* USER CODE BEGIN I2C1_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE END I2C1_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE BEGIN I2C1_Init 1 */

  /* USER CODE END I2C1_Init 1 */
  hi2c1.Instance = I2C1;
  hi2c1.Init.Timing = 0x200009FE;
  hi2c1.Init.OwnAddress1 = 0;
  hi2c1.Init.AddressingMode = I2C_ADDRESSINGMODE_7BIT;
  hi2c1.Init.DualAddressMode = I2C_DUALADDRESS_DISABLE;
  hi2c1.Init.OwnAddress2 = 0;
  hi2c1.Init.OwnAddress2Masks = I2C_OA2_NOMASK;
  hi2c1.Init.GeneralCallMode = I2C_GENERALCALL_DISABLE;
  hi2c1.Init.NoStretchMode = I2C_NOSTRETCH_DISABLE;
  if (HAL_I2C_Init(&hi2c1) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /** Configure Analogue filter
   */
  if (HAL_I2CEx_ConfigAnalogFilter(&hi2c1, I2C_ANALOGFILTER_ENABLE) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /** Configure Digital filter
   */
  if (HAL_I2CEx_ConfigDigitalFilter(&hi2c1, 0) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /* USER CODE BEGIN I2C1_Init 2 */

  /* USER CODE END I2C1_Init 2 */
}

// static void MX_USART1_UART_Init(void)
// {

//   /* USER CODE BEGIN USART1_Init 0 */

//   /* USER CODE END USART1_Init 0 */

//   /* USER CODE BEGIN USART1_Init 1 */

//   /* USER CODE END USART1_Init 1 */
//   huart1.Instance = USART1;
//   huart1.Init.BaudRate = 115200;
//   huart1.Init.WordLength = UART_WORDLENGTH_8B;
//   huart1.Init.StopBits = UART_STOPBITS_1;
//   huart1.Init.Parity = UART_PARITY_NONE;
//   huart1.Init.Mode = UART_MODE_TX;
//   huart1.Init.HwFlowCtl = UART_HWCONTROL_NONE;
//   huart1.Init.OverSampling = UART_OVERSAMPLING_16;
//   if (HAL_UART_Init(&huart1) != HAL_OK)
//   {
//     Error_Handler();
//   }
//   /* USER CODE BEGIN USART1_Init 2 */

//   /* USER CODE END USART1_Init 2 */
// }

/**
 * @brief GPIO Initialization Function
 * @param None
 * @retval None
 */
static void MX_GPIO_Init(void)
{

  /* GPIO Ports Clock Enable */
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOB_CLK_ENABLE();
}

/* USER CODE BEGIN 4 */

/* USER CODE END 4 */

/**
 * @brief  This function is executed in case of error occurrence.
 * @retval None
 */
void Error_Handler(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN Error_Handler_Debug */
  /* User can add his own implementation to report the HAL error return state */
  __disable_irq();
  while (1)
  {
  }
  /* USER CODE END Error_Handler_Debug */
}

int8_t bmm150_aux_read(uint8_t reg_addr, uint8_t *reg_data, uint16_t len, void *intf_ptr)
{
  int8_t rslt;
  rslt = bmi160_aux_read(reg_addr, reg_data, len, &bmi);
  return rslt;
}

int8_t bmm150_aux_write(uint8_t reg_addr, uint8_t *reg_data, uint16_t len, void *intf_ptr)
{
  int8_t rslt;
  rslt = bmi160_aux_write(reg_addr, reg_data, len, &bmi);
  return rslt;
}

#ifdef USE_FULL_ASSERT
/**
 * @brief  Reports the name of the source file and the source line number
 *         where the assert_param error has occurred.
 * @param  file: pointer to the source file name
 * @param  line: assert_param error line source number
 * @retval None
 */
void assert_failed(uint8_t *file, uint32_t line)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 6 */
  /* User can add his own implementation to report the file name and line number,
     ex: printf("Wrong parameters value: file %s on line %d\r\n", file, line) */
  /* USER CODE END 6 */
}
#endif /* USE_FULL_ASSERT */
```

The print statements in the while loop are supposed to provide the results. The Accel data and Gyro data both are 0 for x,y,z and 0 on the sensor time. The mag data provides -32768 for the x,y,z values. I have checked that all functions return 0 several times but still I am confused on why I am not getting good data. I am also using the latest code from Bosch's github repo for both the bmi160 and bmm150.

Here is the I2C configure that is called by the MX_12C1_INIT().

```
void HAL_I2C_MspInit(I2C_HandleTypeDef *hi2c)
{
  GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStruct = {0};
  if (hi2c->Instance == I2C1)
  {
    /* USER CODE BEGIN I2C1_MspInit 0 */

    /* USER CODE END I2C1_MspInit 0 */

    /**I2C1 GPIO Configuration
    PB8     ------> I2C1_SCL
    PB9     ------> I2C1_SDA
    */
    GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_8 | GPIO_PIN_9;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_AF_OD;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_HIGH;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Alternate = GPIO_AF1_I2C1;
    HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOB, &GPIO_InitStruct);

    /* Peripheral clock enable */
    __HAL_RCC_I2C1_CLK_ENABLE();
    /* USER CODE BEGIN I2C1_MspInit 1 */

    /* USER CODE END I2C1_MspInit 1 */
  }
}
```

This is using a STM32F030R8T6 Processor that is supplied voltage by a st-link-v2.

[image]

Comment: That's just too much. Start with something simple and move forward with a small steps. First make sure that you can read a single bit of info - some register, with a known value, like chip ID.

Answer (score 0):

When creating circuitry, a number of issues could arise during the process which we are not aware of. A common issue is powering one are of the circuit with one voltage and communicating with the circuit using a different voltage. Both sensor and PLC need to be running on same voltage over the comms channel / pins.

The next step to debugging a circuit in this case would be to ensure that your "breakout board" or the sensor have pull up resistors. I have always found (40-50 different samples) that I do not need to add pull up resistors to break out boards. I have never had to add any.

The next issue I usually run into is addressing. Most ICs / sensors have a mechanism which allows you to select which address to use. If you hold the voltage low (0v), it will have a certain address while if you hold the voltage high (3.3v or 5v or whatever) it might be a different address. If you failed to add any connector to the pin (floating), it will be invalid and sensor will not start.

Another common issue is protocol. Some chips enable certain protocols by default and you may need to modify the internal settings in order to change them. By protocol, I am referring to either I2C, SPI or U(S)ART. This is unlikely but I've added it for completeness.

The issue most people *think* is happening is that the sensor is fried due to ESD. The likelyhood of your circuit being damaged is wildly low and it is certainly stronger than you think. I doubt you have damaged the circuit in any way.

To answer further, i would certainly require a picture of your circuit as the driver code *should* not be an issue at all. I generally find that driver code, even when outdated or for an earlier model, will generally still gather simple data relative to the ealier model.

Comment: That makes sense but could you provide where you saw this in the documentation or how to implement this functionality? Thanks

Comment: Upon further digging, I looked into the examples Bosch provides for their bmi160 driver and from what they showed compared to what I have, the chip should be able to provide me data at least for the accelerometer and the gyroscope.

Comment: I've added a link to driver code. This should provide a great start to interacting with the device.

Comment: This is what I am using at the moment. Per the github page from bosch in the examples I am doing similar to what it is doing, I am just not using the coines library instead I am using HAL. Evening using the wiki for using FIFO does not yield me any for getting data.

Comment: I ran the self test for both the bmi sensor and the bmm sensor and all three fail even though initializing the sensor does not throw any errors

Comment: Only one voltage line on circuit? You use 3.3 OR 5 v, not both? You need the 3.3v

Comment: I am using 3.3v. I was doing research and the self tests should be able to execute right after the initializations due to how they are coded but I am still getting errors no matter where I put the tests

Comment: Do you have external pull-up resistors configured on your I2C SDA and SCL lines? I don't see where you're configuring the I2C GPIO. I would've some `HAL_GPIO_Init()` calls with `GPIO_AF4_I2C1` for `I2C``

Comment: I added in the I2c code to the above to help answer your question. I currently do not have any pull up resistors on either of the lines though would that be impacting this since I can initialize just fine? The initialization for BMI and BMM both call the read and write from i2c.

Comment: Then you need to fit pullup resistors to both the SDA and SCL lines. 10k should be fine for 100kHz I2C.

Comment: Ok I will give that a try. With GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL should I change this to Pull High or leave it as it is?

Comment: I added the resistors to the board side with still the same results. I tried adding the resistors to the sda and scl on the IMU board then the initialization does not finish.

Comment: I agree that a circuit issue is most likely as the driver code *should* be able to interact without issue. Please add circuitry details.

Comment: @PatrickSturm I have supplied a picture of how I have set up the board. I have everything using 3.3v and that is in spec for the BMX160 and I use a st-link-v2.

Comment: So at this point I have tried programming this in Rust and using my Arduino to see if it was my code. Both my Rust code and the Arduino both failed so I am inclined to say that the chip is bad. I am going to work on getting a new on soldered to see if that solves my problems.

Comment: I do need to stress how unlikely that is. I really do believe there is a small issue which has been overlooked.

Comment: @PatrickSturm Either my original solder job was bad or the chip was bad. I soldered a new chip with different solder and it is now working.